# Using custom Python CDK lib build from Typescript source using jsii and jsii-pacmak

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I managed to generate 2 files defining a Python lib build from a Typascript code base as described in the AWS workshop:

https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/d93fec4c-fb0f-4813-ac90-758cb5527f2f/en-US/walkthrough/typescript/sample/target-construct/build-and-package

This generates two files for the Python lib.

- personal.mypackage-0.1.0.tar.gz
- personal.mypackage-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl

How would I use the generated lib in a Python project after I launched one with the command `cdk init --language=python`.

I am confused about:

- Where should I place the packages?
- Should I extract the packaged files?

I tried searching the internet however the only example I found was using Typescript constructs build using jsii and sjii-pacmak in a C# project.

Answer (score 0):

`jsii-pacmak` has created the Python artifacts as tarball and wheel package. To use it in your Python CDK stack, you need to first install the packages and then import the modules. First initialize your application in Python:

```
cdk init sample-app --language python
source .venv/bin/activate
```

Now install:

```
python3 -m pip install personal.mypackage-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

It will be installed at `<home_dir>/.venv/lib/python3.x/site-packages/`. You could extract the tarball inside `.jsii` and see what constructs you have packaged. Import them in your Python CDK stack:

There are three important files:

- cdk.json - Tells where your app entry point app.py is located
- app.py - Application entry point
- stack.py - app stack where you define your CDK IaC